# Why is Microsoft's Log Parser still at version 2.2 (from 2005)

Tags: logparser

Is there a new or different product that people are using?
Are there no new features people can think of?
Is it not being used by many people?
Or, has Microsoft just decided not to invest any more resources into it?

I am trying to assess whether this is still a good enough tool to use, even though it appears it is no longer being supported or developed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 6):

The basic log file format has remained the same through the last four(?) versions of IIS, so I'd say it's probably just the case that nothing else needs to be added.

Comment: Yes that's true, it's a flexible tool. But I suspect Microsoft don't care as much about the other log types... :)

Comment: What do you want that it doesn't do?  Besides the fact it doesn't have it's own product team, I'm willing to bet it's not very high on Microsoft's list of things to upgrade.

Comment: Also, log file formats are quite standardised anyway (including the other log types supported by this tool): once they work, they don't change much.

Comment: I am just wary of using a product that seems to be abandoned.

Comment: I *really* wouldn't worry about it. If you test it well, and it does what you want, it's not going to suddenly break.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend it.

We use it at a client site to parse 50 logs from 30 applications on an hourly basis. It's fast enough and with the ability to parse custom logs (We have http logs parsing), there is little limitation.

We are looking into Splunk now though for more real time analysis.